# How to replace a string only in lines matching a pattern?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I want to replace "stringA" with "stringB" in all files that contain a pattern which stringA is part of, and do the replacement only in those lines.
Using sed I was able to replace the strings in the whole file, not with line resolution.

### For example:

I want to replace ip4_addr with dest_ip4_addr only in those lines (if the line contains stringA) from all those files:

```
sergey@ipkt /proj/sergey/platform (master) $ git grep -n ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4
ipkt-app/include/ipkt_dp_filter_api.h:7:ipkt_err_t ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_add(uint16 vlan, uint32 ip4_addr, uint32 ip4_mask, bool is_stateful);
ipkt-app/include/ipkt_dp_filter_api.h:9:ipkt_err_t ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_delete(uint16 vlan, uint32 ip4_addr, uint32 ip4_mask);
ipkt-app/ipkt-bm/ipkt_cmd.c:559:        SHR_IF_ERR_EXIT(ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_add(vid, ip4_addr, ip4_mask, statefull_flag));
ipkt-app/ipkt-bm/ipkt_cmd.c:563:        SHR_IF_ERR_EXIT(ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_delete(vid, ip4_addr, ip4_mask));
ipkt-app/ipkt-bm/ipkt_dp_filter_api.c:5:ipkt_err_t ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_add(uint16 vlan, uint32 ip4_addr, uint32 ip4_mask, bool is_stateful)
ipkt-app/ipkt-bm/ipkt_dp_filter_api.c:13:ipkt_err_t ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_delete(uint16 vlan, uint32 ip4_addr, uint32 ip4_mask)
ipkt-app/ipkt-rpc/server_rpc_wrappers.cpp:396:int rpc_ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_add(uint16 vlan, std::string ip4_addr, uint32 mask, bool is_stateful){
ipkt-app/ipkt-rpc/server_rpc_wrappers.cpp:402:    CALL_IPKT(ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_add(vlan, ipkt_ip, mask, is_stateful));
ipkt-app/ipkt-rpc/server_rpc_wrappers.cpp:405:int rpc_ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_delete(uint16 vlan, std::string ip4_addr, uint32 mask){
ipkt-app/ipkt-rpc/server_rpc_wrappers.cpp:411:    CALL_IPKT(ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_delete(vlan, ipkt_ip, mask));
ipkt-app/ipkt-rpc/server_rpc_wrappers.cpp:591:    srv.bind("ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_add", &rpc_ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_add);
ipkt-app/ipkt-rpc/server_rpc_wrappers.cpp:592:    srv.bind("ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_delete", &rpc_ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_delete);
```

### Things I tried:

```
grep -rl ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4 ipkt-app/ | grep -v swp | xargs sed -i 's/ip4_addr/dest_ip4_addr/'
```

This changed extra lines I didn't want to change.

```
git grep -l ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4 | xargs sed -i 's/ipkt_dp_filter_ipv4_.*uint32 /& dest_/'
```

Also tried with regex, but I don't know how to replace a string within a regex.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Include your failed attempts in your question.

Comment: It's not clear what the second string is. Please, add the expected result for your example, and give some strings that mustn't be modify.

Answer (score 1):

using awk

`awk '{ if($0~/stringA/) gsub(/ip4_addr/,"dest_ip4_addr",$0)} 1 < input file'`

Demo: Replace `a` where the record starts with `a`

```
$echo -e  "abca\nefga\n123a"
abca
efga
123a
$echo -e  "abca\nefga\n123a"  | awk '{ if($0~/^a/) gsub(/a/,"d",$0)} 1' 
dbcd
efga
123a
$
```